# ADAL for iOS build error on Xcode 7.3

Tags: xcode7, office365, adal

We are using ADALiOS version 1.2.5. We have updated Xcode to version 7.3. Microsoft ADAL library fails to compile. The errors are as follows:

- Could not build Objective C module 'ADALiOS'
- Build errors in file : ADPersistentTokenCacheStore.

Please Advice

Comment: Forgot to mention that we developing our app in swift

Comment: Have you created a bridging header for this C module?

Comment: Thanks for the prompt comment. No I have not as it was not needed in XCode version 7.2. Will try creating it and respond.

Comment: see below my detailed response. let me know how it goes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't created a bridging header for C libraries, you need to do so.
Right click on your project, select add Objective-C file. Xcode will ask you if you would like to create a bridging header, select yes and then import needed C libraries.

here is how to do this:
https://spin.atomicobject.com/2015/02/23/c-libraries-swift/

Comment: Thanks Mostafa !! Creating a Module Map was crucial..... That was the magic potion missing !!!. **Creating a module map file is as easy as creating a new file in xcode and then changing its name and extension**